# Is there an appropriate way to reuse Redux aware components?

Tags: reactjs, redux, reusability

I have a complex component with dropdown and a table that uses selectors to calculate values. I want to reuse this component. Is there an appropriate way to do this?

Now I reuse the component twice. So now when I change the dropdown in the first component, the dropdown value in the second component are changing too.

Comment: Make your component more reusable by adding more props which may be values or functions. This question is way generic can you post your component here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

In your reducers, you can use different functions to manage two different components. Just provide a different name. You can also use the same functionality, but now they work independently. Use this as a sample, if you need more info let me know.

```
case 'TOGGLE_DROPDOWN_1':
      return {
        ...state,
        toggleDropdown1: !state.toggleDropdown1
      }
case 'TOGGLE_DROPDOWN_2':
      return {
        ...state,
        toggleDropdown2: !state.toggleDropdown2
}
```

And then in your actions

```
export const toggleDropdown1 = () => {
  return {
    type: 'TOGGLE_DROPDOWN_1',
  }
}

export const toggleDropdown2 = () => {
  return {
    type: 'TOGGLE_DROPDOWN_2',
  }
}
```